# How do I implement "count if value is 1 and if value to left is present in separate column"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my setup:

```
Sheet 1      Sheet 2
A     B      A     B    
John  Y      John  1
Jack  N      Jack  2
James Y      James 3
Jayne Y      Jayne 2
```

This list continues with a class of names.
Sheet 1 Column B attributes a yes or no value to a name, and sheet 2 Column B divides the names into 1 of 3 categories(1, 2 or 3).

I want to count all of the 1's that are also Yes's. The name order is fixed between the two sheets if that makes it easier or I can create a list of names that are 'Yes' if that makes it easier to match.

Comment: What have you tried? `CountIfs()` should work.

Comment: Can you do a `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)` to bring the `Y`/`N` to Sheet 2 and then do `=IF(AND(C2="Y",B2=1),1,0)` to get the `Y` & `1` combo you need, and then just sum the column?

Comment: This would work but im trying to find a way around having to create a column C with the yes/no data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `COUNTIFS` function which counts based on multiple criteria,

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B:B,1,Sheet1!B:B,"Y")`

`Sheet2!B:B` is checked for `1` **and** `Sheet1!B:B` for `Y`.